# Jenkinsfile Declarative Pipeline: Checking out another repo in stage step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have my Jenkinsfile located in repo "A" and I was to checkout a repo in repo "B". What's the correct way to do that?

This is how I have currently doing it, but it's not working:

```
    stage("Checkout my repo repo ") {
        steps {
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], 
                extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', 
            relativeTargetDir: 'copy-repo-here']],
                userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'my-creds', 
                url: 'git@github.com:my-git-repo.git']]]) 
       }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the pieline output with us?